# Will my kids ever grow up?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Will my kids ever grow up in Skyrim? I've had the game for a year now and I've had them for a long time. Will they ever grow up? I go to other people's houses and their kids are grown. I really need to know.

Answer (score 14):

**No.**

No one ages at all in Skyrim. There are children and elders only because the programmers/designers put them in there to be children and elders; there's not a single NPC that will age a single day, no matter how long you play the game. (Well, there might be a scripted event in some quest somewhere that does it to one, but outside of that...)